# How to use window in getStaticProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to load a specific configuration (opening hours, company address,…) based on the subdomain. Thus I want to run a single instance of NextJS for different clients (each client has a subdomain).

I try

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const subdomain = /:\/\/([^\/?]+)/.exec(window.location.href)[1].split(".")[0];

  const config = mysqlquery(subdomain);

  return {
    props: {
      config,
    }
  }   
}
```

and I get window is not defined.

Comment: getStaticProps fetches data at build time. I think you should use `getServerSideProps(context)` instead, using context.req.host instead of window.location.href.

Comment: With that I‘d not present a skeleton while config is loading, correct?

Comment: Right. If you want to run a single instance of NextJS for different clients, I think you should run each instance in its own server (or serverless deployment) and route the different domains to different servers

Comment: I‘m open for better solutions. But I want to avoid maintenance of multiple instances of the app. For me this is copy and paste auf the ./ folder and npm build && npm Start many times and handeling all the ports. This is why I plan to have only one instance.

Comment: If you already have a nextjs instance for each client, why do you need to load the config based on the request location? Doesn't each instance know it's subdomain at build time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the url using context.req.headers.referer, being your code as follows:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {

const subdomain = /:\/\/([^\/?]+)/.exec(context.req.headers.referer).split(".")[0];

const config = mysqlquery(subdomain);

return {
    props: {
      config,
    }
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First install absoluteUrl then you should request to your local api to find subdomain let see the code:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
   const req = await 
   fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/hello");
  const dd = await req.json();
   console.log("sub", dd);
     return {
     props: {
    aboutData: [],
      },
   };
```

}

now in pages/api/hello.js

```
import absoluteUrl from "next-absolute-url";
     export default async function 
            handler(req,res) {
  const { origin } = absoluteUrl(req);
  let subdomain = origin.match(/\w+/);
  console.log("request ", subdomain);
  return res.status(200).json({ subDomain: 
     subdomain });
    }
```

it will send an array subdomain is the first index of array actually i am not sure about regex that i write you can check if not work write your own regex to determin the subdomain

Comment: You shouldn't call internal API routes from `getStaticProps`. The code you have in `api/hello`'s handler can be used directly inside `getStaticProps`.

Comment: But you don't have access to host URL or origin in getStaticProps because of that We send request to our api and our api can varify host and domain.